# remove dialogbuilder default background color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, styling

I created a dialogbuilder override with custom shape, colors, list etc which looks like this:

[image]

It looks like there is some default background still active as you can see by the corners. Can I remove this or set it to transparent?

Please note that the white color is not coming from the white below the purple

Code below for refference

```
        emptyNewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_mainlayout, null));

            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the window and set the window color to transparent something like below.

> alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

```
  final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_mainlayout, null));
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: is the white color still coming

Comment: i am sorry I still had builder.show() instead of alertdialog.show(). This does work for me